# Flex Detecting Dragged Data

Tags: apache-flex, list, actionscript, drag-and-drop, components

I have a list that accepts drops. When an item is dropped (DragEvent.DRAG_DROP) I need to collect the data that is dropped, however I have found nothing in the event that helps me do so, `event.dragInitiator.selectedItems` would work but gives me an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data should be in `event.dragSource`.  You'll have to check for the proper format using `hasFormat()` and retrieve it with `dataForFormat()`.  Here are the docs for [DragSource](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/DragSource.html).

Code would be something like this (assuming this is Flex 4):

```
// In dragDrop handler or dragComplete
if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("itemsByIndex"))
{
    var items:Vector.<Object> = event.dragSource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex") as Vector.<Object>;
    // Do stuff with items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also listen to changing dataProvider.

```
list.dataProvider.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, list_dataProvider_change);

...

protected function list_dataProvider_change(e :CollectionEvent) :void
{
    if (e.kind == CollectionEventKind.REMOVE)
        trace('list element removed from - index', e.location);
    else if (e.kind == CollectionEventKind.ADD)
        trace('list element added to - index', e.location);   
}
```